# SQL If value exist show a column and show yes in there

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to write a query to add a new column if there is data in one of the column in the name of score if there is not data for some of its rows in the table the query should create a column and show "no" but if there is data in there it should show "yes" as in the below.

Table

```
Name      Phone     Score    
Ali       1111      90
Karim     2222      80
Ramin     33333     10
Millad    3333      
Rawof     5555
```

After query it should shows

```
Name      Phone     Score    new_column
Ali       1111      90       yes
Karim     2222      80       yes
Ramin     33333     10       yes
Millad    3333               no
Rawof     5555               no
```

Comment: Could I ask why you want to do this? In general it sounds like a bad idea to me as then you will have two sources of truth for this property, now when you update a row you (presumably) need to make sure new_column continues to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use CASE WHEN with coalesce function.

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN coalesce(Score,'') <> '' THEN 'yes' else 'no' end 'new_column'
FROM T
```

**Edit**

In Oracle document about [NULL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF51094)

> Oracle Database treats a character value with a length of zero as null.

```
SELECT t1.*,(CASE WHEN t1.Score IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' else 'no' end) as new_column
FROM T t1
```

Comment: beat me to it by 30 seconds

Comment: when i try this in oracle apex SQL command section it throw an error     ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @MelladQarizada You can try to use your table name instead of `T`

Comment: You will need to prefix `*`, for example `t.*`.

Comment: However, `<> ''` will never be true if this is Oracle. Also Oracle doesn't require brackets around select list expressions, and the double-quotes just force the column name to lower case (although possibly that's what the OP wanted).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thank for your remind I edit my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `CASE WHEN` Expression

```
select name, phone, score, case when score is null or score='' then 'no' else 'yes' end
from tablename
```

Comment: @MelladQarizada, if it helped u please mark it as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE
(
    [Name] VARCHAR(32),
    Phone VARCHAR(16),
    Score int
)
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
('Ali', '1111', 90),
('Karim', '2222', 80),
('Ramin', '33333', 10),
('Millad', '3333', NULL ),
('Rawof', '5555', NULL)

SELECT
    [Name],
    Phone,
    CASE
        WHEN SCORE IS NULL THEN 'no'
        ELSE 'yes' 
    END as new_column
FROM
    @table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`, `nvl2` or `decode`.

```
select name, phone, score
     , case when score is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as new_column1
     , nvl2(score,'yes','no') as new_column1
     , decode(score, null,'no', 'yes') as new_column3
from   demo;
```

`nvl2` is the most compact, but it is a little cryptic. I'd probably choose `case` myself.

If you want this expression to be permanently available, you could make it a virtual column:

```
create table demo (name, phone, score) as
select 'Ali',    1111,  90   from dual union all
select 'Karim',  2222,  80   from dual union all
select 'Ramin',  33333, 10   from dual union all
select 'Millad', 3333,  null from dual union all
select 'Rawof',  5555,  null from dual;

alter table demo add new_column generated always as (case when score is null then 'no' else 'yes' end);

select * from demo;

NAME                                PHONE      SCORE NEW_COLUMN
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
Ali                                  1111         90 yes
Karim                                2222         80 yes
Ramin                               33333         10 yes
Millad                               3333            no
Rawof                                5555            no

5 rows selected.
```